# Will this MOSFET switch circuit work?

Tags: led, mosfet, switches, integrated-circuit, ldr

[image: MOSFET LED strip switch circuit]

I should point out that the LED I'm trying to switch is actually an LED strip with a one meter length and a total of 60 LEDs. Total power consumption is 4.8W at 12V. By the way, 'IC1' is the 7805, which converts the 12V DC into 5V DC.

This is the MOSFET I plan on using: http://panda-bg.com/datasheet/860-064009-Transistor-IRF530-ST.pdf (IRF530-ST)

I'm new to the field of electronics so I am not quite sure if it will work so any kind of feedback is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correction to the schematic: your IRF530 is *installed backwards*. You don't want the body diode "pointed" in the same direction as your LED string. The N-FET source terminal should be connected to the negative terminal of your 12V supply.

While using a [LMx24](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lm2902-n.pdf) as a comparator isn't the best, since its input common mode range and its output range includes the negative/ground supply and the threshold voltage of the IRF530 is at most 4V, this circuit (with the corrected FET direction) will mostly work if you use a LM7805 or higher voltage (accounting for dropout, 5 to 9V should be a reasonable choice of 78xx). From the comments: remember that the IRF530 has its on resistance rated at a \$V_{GS}\$ of 10V. Acceptable performance may be found for this application at lower gate voltage, but choosing a different FET with a "logic level" gate drive capability would help if a 7805 is used.

However, your op-amp (being used as a comparator) has no hysteresis. This means that at certain light levels, you will have a flickering LED string because your threshold potentiometer and the LDR/resistor divider have almost the same outputs. For some good information on why you want hysteresis and how to implement it, check out [TI's TIDU020A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf) document. The difference in their circuits is:

[image: TI's example schematic for adding hysteresis to a comparator in document TIDU020A]

Comment: Note 5V won't turn the MOSFET fully on, its on resistance is specified at Vgs=10V. (The threshold, 2-4V, is where it conducts 0.25 mA, not very bright). You could happily run the whole thing off 12V if it's a stable supply, or a 9V regulator should be good enough otherwise. For hysteresis, all you need is a resistor from opamp VOUT to IN+, much higher (say 20-50x) than the potentiometer R3 - say 220K or 470K.

Comment: @BrianDrummond But if I switch directly to the 12V supply, would the LM124-324 handle the 12 Volts?

Comment: Check its datasheet...

Answer (score 4):

To what's been said in other answers I'd add this:

- The IRF530 might have a threshold voltage as high as 4 V. If you drive it with 5 V, that's only one volt above threshold and it won't be very strongly on. You will not achieve the low Rds(on) specified in the datasheet (that value is specified with a Vgs of 10 V).

  This could lead to excessive heating in the MOSFET.

  I would recommend using a comparator chip rather than an op-amp. If you choose one with an open-collector output (which is common) and appropriate ratings for maximum output voltage (12 V), and provide a pull-up to 12 V, the FET gate can be pulled to 12 V when "on".

  Or choose a FET with a guaranteed Rds(on) at 5 V Vgs. The IRF530 is really overkill for your design since it is specified for 14 A and you are only switching about 400 mA (12 V / 4.8 V).
- Leaving the three unused op-amps in the '324 package unconnected could lead to oscillations and affect the behavior of the op-amp you are using, or overheat the '324 chip. Typically, unused devices in op-amp packages can be connected as voltage followers (with the outputs not connected to anything) to avoid this issue.

Comment: I understand that this particular MOSFET is a bit overkill but I plan on adding more LED strips to the circuit in the future so I don't really feel the need to change it. It just makes it a lot more future proof I guess :D On a side note can you please elaborate on how to connect the 3 other op amps as voltage followers?? :)

Comment: Google "op amp voltage follower" and look at the image results.

Comment: If you're going to stick with the IRF530 then find a way to drive the gate to 10 V for on.

Comment: Good note on the unused op-amps. I was thinking about that, then forgot to mention it. If possible, connect the voltage follower to the middle of a voltage divider as best-practice.

Comment: @The Photon I got it. Thank you very much for your feedback dude and I'm sorry if I wasted your time with my thoughtlessness. Have a very nice day! :)